# Android alarm manager with flexible schedule?

Tags: android, android-layout, service, alarmmanager

I'm developing a background service and I want the user to choose when the service runs so I've included two libraries from github to make a date range and time range pickers, along with an recurrence picker.
I can get the user's choices in a textview. I'm new to android so my only idea was to store these choices in a local database and then make the alarm manager access the stored data and the following parameters will be set with that data.

```
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, alarmIntent);
```

But I feel like I'm complicating things. If I pass the parameters directly to the activity containing the alarm manager, will they be stored and kept even if the user shuts down his phone? unless the user changes the alarm manager parameters through the interface, the previous values should be kept even when the phone restarts.

These are the different interfaces offered to the user to choose the schedule for the service.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should save these data in [shared preference](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) and then read from it and start a repeating alarm. shared preference keep your data even after device restarts. if you have question about `service` or `alarm`, that's something different and you should ask it more clearly.

Comment: no I've used the alarm manager and services before but I fixed the alarm parameter in the code and I was wondering if they can be stored somewhere for the alarm manager to access them. I've never saved data in shared preference though so I'll read about it. Thank you.

Comment: just cancel current alarm and set another one with new schedule